# Qgis python ComboBox: Combination of fixed and free Items

Tags: qgis, python, combo-box

I want to built a ComboBox to select a given plotting scale out of a list **or** ask for a different scale (e.g. '1:625') as Textinput in the same ComboBox. The combobox is changed to 'editable' and I'm able to fill in the digits. But they are not read.
The list will work fine -  but how must the code looks like to insert the free choosen scale (last item)?

```
    self.dlg.comboBoxScale.clear()
    self.dlg.comboBoxScale.addItem('1:500', 500)
    self.dlg.comboBoxScale.addItem('1:1000', 1000)
    self.dlg.comboBoxScale.addItem('1:1500', 1500)
    self.dlg.comboBoxScale.addItem('1:2000', 2000)
    ...
    # Item with free digits
    self.dlg.comboBoxScale.addItem('1:')    #????
```

Any Idea?